# Blazor @attributes

Tags: blazor

I try to understand the @attributes parameter and I don't understand a behaviour.

I have made a component called PushButton.razor

```
<button class="button primary" @attributes="UserAttributes" disabled="@IsDisabled">
@Text
</button>
```

In the related css file I have

```
.button {
border: none;
padding: 10px 40px;
font-size: 20px;
border-radius: 3px;
cursor: pointer;
transition: 0.3s
```

}

```
.button:hover:enabled {
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

.primary {
background-color: blue;
color: white;
```

}

In the related cs file I have

```
 [Parameter]
    public string? Text { get; set; }

 [Parameter]
    public bool IsDisabled { get; set; } = false;

[Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues =true)]
    public Dictionary<string, object> UserAttributes { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

Now I create 2 buttons as follows:

```
<PushButton Text="My button"></PushButton>
<PushButton Text="My button" style="background-color:burlywood"></PushButton>
```

Wenn I run the app I get

[image]

And if I hover over the first button the hover background is displayed but not if I hover over the second button.

[image]

I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's has anything to do with attributes.  You are overriding your CSS with `style`.

You can refactor your code.

```css
.button {
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s
}

    .button:hover:enabled {
        background-color: #cccccc;
    }

.primary {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}

.burlywood {
    background-color: burlywood;
    color: white;
}
```

Your PushButton:

```cs
<button class="@this.Class" disabled="@IsDisabled">
    @Text
</button>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string? Text { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public string? Class { get; set; } = "button primary";

    [Parameter] public bool IsDisabled { get; set; } = false;
}
```

And example:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.


<div>
    <PushButton Text="My button 1"></PushButton>
    <PushButton Text="My button 2" Class="button burlywood"></PushButton>
</div>
```

However, if you're building CSS from Parameters and Attributes you should use a utility class like this to build out the CSS in the component.

```cs
/// ============================================================
/// Author: Shaun Curtis, Cold Elm Coders
/// License: Use And Donate
/// If you use it, donate something to a charity somewhere
/// ============================================================
namespace Blazr.Components;

public sealed class CSSBuilder
{
    private Queue<string> _cssQueue = new Queue<string>();

    public static CSSBuilder Class(string? cssFragment = null)
        => new CSSBuilder(cssFragment);

    public CSSBuilder() { }

    public CSSBuilder(string? cssFragment)
        => AddClass(cssFragment ?? String.Empty);

    public CSSBuilder AddClass(string? cssFragment)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cssFragment))
            _cssQueue.Enqueue(cssFragment);
        return this;
    }

    public CSSBuilder AddClass(IEnumerable<string> cssFragments)
    {
        cssFragments.ToList().ForEach(item => _cssQueue.Enqueue(item));
        return this;
    }

    public CSSBuilder AddClass(bool WhenTrue, string cssFragment)
        => WhenTrue ? this.AddClass(cssFragment) : this;

    public CSSBuilder AddClass(bool WhenTrue, string? trueCssFragment, string? falseCssFragment)
        => WhenTrue ? this.AddClass(trueCssFragment) : this.AddClass(falseCssFragment);

    public CSSBuilder AddClassFromAttributes(IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object> additionalAttributes)
    {
        if (additionalAttributes != null && additionalAttributes.TryGetValue("class", out var val))
            _cssQueue.Enqueue(val.ToString() ?? string.Empty);
        return this;
    }

    public CSSBuilder AddClassFromAttributes(IDictionary<string, object> additionalAttributes)
    {
        if (additionalAttributes != null && additionalAttributes.TryGetValue("class", out var val))
            _cssQueue.Enqueue(val.ToString() ?? string.Empty);
        return this;
    }

    public string Build(string? CssFragment = null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CssFragment)) _cssQueue.Enqueue(CssFragment);
        if (_cssQueue.Count == 0)
            return string.Empty;
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var str in _cssQueue)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str)) sb.Append($" {str}");
        }
        return sb.ToString().Trim();
    }
}
```

`PushButton` then looks like:

```cs
<button class="@this.Class" disabled="@IsDisabled">
    @Text
</button>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string? Text { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public string? ColourClass { get; set; } = "primary";

    [Parameter] public bool IsDisabled { get; set; } = false;

    private CSSBuilder cSSBuilder = new();

    private string Class => cSSBuilder
        .AddClass("button")
        .AddClass(this.ColourClass)
        .Build();
}
```

And the Demo:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.


<div>
    <PushButton Text="My button 1"></PushButton>
    <PushButton Text="My button 2" ColourClass="burlywood"></PushButton>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But with [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues =true)] and then with <PushButton Text="My button" style="background-color:burlywood"></PushButton> I thought that just the background-color would be over written because the unmatched value is background-color. In fact all the other properties remain unchanged so not all CSS properties are overwritten. It is just background for hover which is no longer actif. Even so your solution works fine, I don't understand why changing one propery with the unmatched value parameter changes the hover background.